# Behavior of \\ in Plain TeX

Tags: macros, plain-tex, catcodes

According to `\show`, the pre-defined control sequence `\\` is supposed expand to its argument without the suffix "pt":

```
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
**\show\\
> \\=macro:
#1pt->#1.
<*> \show\
```

However, using it fails:

```
*\message{\\5pt}
! Argument of \\ has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<to be read again>
```

When defining a macro that has the same definition as `\\`, everything works as expected:

```
*\def\mymacro #1pt{#1}

\show\mymacro
> \mymacro=macro:
#1pt->#1.

*\message{\mymacro5pt}
5
```

How can this be explained?

Comment: This behavior of ``\\`` is undocumented and should not be relied upon. It's used for defining `\getf@ctor` which, in turn, is used in `\sh@ft`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What `\show` doesn't show is that the `p` and the `t` are expected to have catcode 12 (`other`), since they were assigned that catcode when `\\` was defined. Your definition of `\mymacro` is therefore not the same, since here the letters are indeed letters (catcode `11`). Why did Knuth define a delimited macro with such strange catcodes? Because this way, `\\` can be used to strip the `pt` when reading a dimen register, which tex outputs with all characters (except space) of catcode `other`. For example: `\expandafter\\\the\fontdimen2\font`.

Knuth explains this dirty trick in the TeXbook, p. 375, where it also becomes clear that `\\` is just an auxiliary command and, as @egreg comments, shouldn't be relied upon.

The LaTeX2e equivalent for `\\` has a (slightly) more telling name: `\rem@pt`; there is also the handy `\strip@pt`, which is defined as `\expandafter\rem@pt\the`, so that you can simply say `\strip@pt\@tempdima` to strip the `pt` from `\@tempdima`. And LaTeX3 provides, with a different syntax, the internal function `\__dim_strip_pt:n{<dimension expression>}`.

Comment: Is there a comparable "pt" stripping command in LaTeX?  Because up to now, I've gotten around that problem by setting a count variable equal to a length, and it stores it in some internal non-dimensional way.