# why can't \the be expanded?

Tags: macros, expansion, lengths

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tracingmacros=2
\newlength{\len} \setlength{\len}{1cm}  we want to write out \verb$\len$ in cm

\the\len { oops, answer in pt}

\setlength{\len}{0.0352\len}
\the\len { good, now we just need to replace pt with cm}

\def\num#1pt{#1cm}
\num1pt { so far so good}

\def\temp{1pt}
\num\temp { not so hot} 0pt %0pt added to end of line just to prevent error message

\expandafter\num\temp   { that works}

\expandafter\num\the\len { but not that} 0pt

\edef\temp{\the\len}
\expandafter\num\temp { okay I'm stuck} 0pt

\makeatletter
\strip@pt\len cm Thank you, that works great!
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

The document IS the question.

If you want to know what I wanted this for, check out `\whereami` in 
http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/speaker.pdf

Comment: see \strip@pt defined in latex format, you could use that, or to define your own, you need p and t to be catcode 12 not 11

Comment: Perhaps you can (in this and future questions) use a structure were you present the code first, and then explain the problems. This question is really hard to understand in its current form.

Comment: Related: [Stripping the pt from a dimension](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6262) and [Behavior of \\ in Plain TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126123)

Comment: @John  We like to keep questions and answers separate, so I've edited out the answer part you added to the question.

Answer (score 8):

The answer by [A.Ellett](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127211) explains how to get what you want, but it's also worth understanding what is wrong with the approach

```
\def\num#1pt{#1cm}
```

The first thing to note is that `\the` *is* expandable, which you can confirm inside an `\edef`

```
\newdimen\mydimen
\edef\demo{\the\mydimen}
\show\demo
```

gives

```
> \demo=macro:
->0.0pt.
```

What is important here, though, is that `pt` in this is made up of two 'other' (catcode 12) characters, not to 'letters'. Thus to strip off the letters we need to use the correct category code for `p` and `t`. The LaTeX kernel defines `\rem@pt` to do this using

```
\begingroup
  \catcode`P=12
  \catcode`T=12
  \lowercase{
    \def\x{\def\rem@pt##1.##2PT{##1\ifnum##2>\z@.##2\fi}}}
  \expandafter\endgroup\x
```

The idea of this is that `P` and `T` are made into 'other' characters, and used to crate lower case 'other' `p` and `t`. A perhaps clearer definition can be set up  using e-TeX:

```
\makeatletter
\edef\@tempa{%
  \def\noexpand\rem@pt##1\detokenize{pt}{##1}%
}
\@tempa
```

where I'm using `\detokenize` to turn `p` and `t` into 'other' characters without all of the lower case business.

LaTeX provides `\strip@pt` as a wrapper around `\rem@pt`, which can then be used as A.Ellett has demonstrated.

Comment: The detour via the uppercase letters is only necessary to still be able to use the lowercase letters in command names (e.g. for `\rem@pt`), right?

Comment: @cgnieder Yes: if we were not using `p` and `t` within the code block, we'd just change their catcodes directly.

Answer (score 7):

This answer deals with the precision of the conversion of `pt` to `cm`.

### Package `printlen`

Package `printlen` uses simple TeX arithmetic using a factor `0.0351459` in front of a dimen register.

### e-TeX's `\dimexpr`

Much more precise is e-TeX's `\dimexpr`, because it uses a 64-bit product as intermediate value, if a multiplication is followed by a division. The result is rounded to 1/65536, because the smallest unit in TeX is `1sp`.

### Package `fp`

Fixed point arithmetic is provided by package `fp`. It supports numbers from 
-999999999999999999.999999999999999999 to +999999999999999999.999999999999999999. It is the most precise method. The number of digits after the period can be reduced, because TeX smallest unit is `1sp`. Therefore more than seven digits do not make much sense.

### Other packages

- LaTeX3 has a module for fixed point arithmetic.
- `pgf`/`TikZ` comes with several methods:

  - `\pgfmathparse`, ...
  - Fixed Point Arithmetic Library
  - Floating Point Unit Library

### Comparison

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1pt]{geometry}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{printlen}
\newcommand*{\PTtoCMprintlen}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \uselengthunit{cm}%
    \dimen@=#1\relax
    \printlength{\dimen@}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\PTtoCMdimexpr}[1]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr(#1)*254/7227\relax cm%
}

\usepackage{fp}
\newcommand*{\PTtoCMfp}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \dimen@=#1\relax
    \FPset{\PTtoCM@tmp}{\number\dimen@}%
    \FPmul{\PTtoCM@tmp}{\PTtoCM@tmp}{2.54}%
    \FPdiv{\PTtoCM@tmp}{\PTtoCM@tmp}{4736286.72}% 72.27 * 65536
    \FPprint{\PTtoCM@tmp}%
    cm%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\PTtoCMfpround}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \dimen@=#1\relax
    \FPset{\PTtoCM@tmp}{\number\dimen@}%
    \FPmul{\PTtoCM@tmp}{\PTtoCM@tmp}{2.54}%
    \FPdiv{\PTtoCM@tmp}{\PTtoCM@tmp}{4736286.72}% 72.27 * 65536
    \FPround{\PTtoCM@tmp}{\PTtoCM@tmp}{7}%
    \FPprint{\PTtoCM@tmp}%
    cm%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  #1 & \PTtoCMprintlen{#1} & \PTtoCMdimexpr{#1}
     & \PTtoCMfp{#1} & \PTtoCMfpround{#1} \\%  
}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
  & printlen & dimexpr & fp & fpround \\
  \hline
  \test{1cm}
  \test{\the\maxdimen}
  \test{89.3999pt}
  \test{1sp}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- If `1cm` is assigned to a length, it is rounded to the unit `sp`, thus the "exact" result is not `1cm`, thus the result of package `fp` is more correct.
- The number of maximal digits TeX prints in case of its lengths or e-TeX's `\dimexpr` is optimized for the smallest unit `1sp`. After the number is converted from `pt` to the larger unit `cm`, the number becomes to small to be printed and the result is rounded to zero.

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to convert LaTeX internal lengths, which are stored in `pt`, to a more *human readable* format, then you can try something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pttocm}[1]{\texttt{\string#1}=\the#1 is approximately \strip@pt\dimexpr0.03514598#1\relax cm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newlength{\triallen}
\setlength{\triallen}{89.3999pt}

\pttocm{\triallen}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, as @werner has pointed out, you can use the package `printlen` and then

```
\uselengthunit{cm}
\printlength{\triallen}
```

Regarding the *lost space* in your code:  that's because a bare LaTeX macro (that is, one not followed by brackets) gobbles up the following space.

Comment: There is also [`printlen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/printlen).

Comment: Or [`lengthconvert`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lengthconvert) (which is more accurate than `printlen`).

Comment: Just to be picky: the `\expandafter` before `\detokenize` is superfluous, because `\detokenize` looks for an opening brace and expands tokens doing it. But `\texttt{\string#1}` is easier.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for being picky.  I didn't know that.  Noted and changed.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Perhaps you should write up another solution.  I feel a bit weird taking other people's suggestions and continually incorporating them into my own answer.

Comment: Something weird is going on here. Google says that 3.14159cm is [89.3868934 TeX points](https://www.google.com/search?q=3.14159+cm+in+tex+points).

Comment: @A.Ellett if I compile your sample document i get an error: `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.13 \pttocm{\triallen}`

Comment: @kahen TeX's accuracy doesn't go beyond the fourth decimal digit (the fifth may be off by 1) when dimensions are in points, so the conversion using multiplication by 0.03514598 increases the error.

Answer (score 5):

One can use the `lengthconvert` package or directly a LaTeX3 function; the first way is much more customizable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lengthconvert}
\newlength{\len}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\len}{1cm}
\Convert[unit=cm]{\len}

\addtolength{\len}{2.5cm}
\Convert[unit=cm]{\len}

\Convert[unit=cm]{1in}

\Convert[unit=pt,precision=2]{1in}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_to_unit:nn {1in}{1mm}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]